# When did Germany pay the full amount of reparations of the Versailles treaty?

Tags: world-war-two, germany, world-war-one, versailles

I remember it was recently, but I do not know the exact year.

Comment: VtC as trivial - if I copy the question into Google, I find the answer in wikipedia.

Comment: It isnt in wikipedia....i searched the versailles article

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This abcnews article](http://abcnews.go.com/International/germany-makes-final-reparation-payments-world-war/story?id=11755920) states that it was in 2010.

Comment: @tstols: I know it is a bit late now, but that payment was **not** a reparation as required by the Versailles treaty. If you read the article closely, that 2010 payment was the last **interest** payed on foreign bonds issued in 1924 / 1930 *in order* to pay reparations. The last actual *reparation* payment was made in 1931, when they were first suspended, then Hitler declined to resume them in 1933. Germany **never** payed "the full amount".